# Как вывести поля с уникальными значениями?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Необходимо сделать выборку из таблицы:  вывести все поля, где значения определённого столбца уникальны. 
Пробовал:

```
mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT album
FROM interiors WHERE
cat='$folder'",$db);
```

Но при таком запросе извлекаются только сами уникальные значения, а мне необходимо, чтобы извлекались все значения поля (строки) с уникальным "album".

Comment: А что значит "уникальны"? Если не учитывать `cat='$folder'`, то может

    select a.* from interiors a join 
       (select album, count(*) cnt from interiors group by album) b 
        on a.album = b.album where b.cnt = 1;

Comment: @alexlz прямо поэма целая...
select *,count(*) as c from interiors where cat='$folder' group by album having c=1 уже не модно?

Comment: Да нет, вполне модно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from interiors where cat='$folder' group by album
```

Comment: Варинат работает и максимально прост!

Answer (score 0):

Вообще так:

```
SELECT *
FROM interiors
WHERE cat = '$folder'
GROUP BY album
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Но редкая БД (в их число входит MySQL) позволяет получать не агрегированные и не группируемые значения.

Так что лучше так:

```
SELECT *
FROM interiors t1
WHERE
  cat = '$folder' AND
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM interiors t2
    WHERE
      t1.id <> t2.id AND
      t1.album = t2.album
  )
```

Comment: А кто такой `id`?